# how use iframe in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, iframe

I am new in windows phone development. Now I am developing a windows phone application for a asp.net application that we developed before. In asp.net there we showing an advertisement part. There I used iframe in a div to show the advertisement.

Now I also want to show the advertisement in windows phone app too. Is iframe can use in windows phone. I tried it, but showing errors.

Can anyone suggest a good way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the add to be shown in a webbrowser control, or in the app as a popup? Also, please put the code that you tried, to give us some perspective.

Comment: I need to show in web browser control. how can I increase the height of the content in web browser control (not the web browser control's height I mean).

Comment: Yes, IFrame can be used in the WebBrowser control. What errors are you getting?

Comment: <phone:WebBrowser > <iframe ></iframe> </phone:WebBrowser>. I used like this. It showing "The type iframe was not found. Varify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments above, it looks like you are trying to add HTML into your XAML markup. This is not supported by the XAML parser. To create a HTML page with an IFrame, you have to assemble it as a string and send it to the browser control via [WebBrowser.NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28VS.92%29.aspx).